# What are the 15 wires on my 700W BLDC servo motor for?

Tags: servo

So I have this 48V 700W DC servo motor and I cannot find the datasheet from the supplier. Unlike most stepper and servo motors, this one has 15 wires coming out of it. It says that it has an encoder built-in, so I suppose that is partly why it has so many wires.

At least it has a sticker on it that gives some labels. Here is what the label says:

**Red:** +5V
**Blue:** A
**Green:** B
**Yellow:** Z
**Brown:** U
**Gray:** V
**White:** W
**Black:** 0V
**Blue/Black:** A-
**Green/Black:** B-
**Yellow/Black:** Z-
**Brown/Black:** U-
**Gray/Black:** V-
**White/Black:** W-
**Shell:** Shield

If you have any idea what this means or know where I can find out, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.dynapar.com/Technology/Encoder_Basics/Incremental_Encoder/

Comment: @BeB00 would you care to write that into an answer or shall I?

Comment: @BeBoo Thanks. Can you specify where I am supposed to look. It just seems like another supplier website. Or maybe send me a link to some documentation or educational material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comment:

http://dynapar.com/Technology/Encoder_Basics/Incremental_Encoder

"An incremental encoder provides a specified amount of pulses in one rotation of the encoder. The output can be a single line of pulses (an “A” channel) or two lines of pulses (an “A” and “B” channel) that are offset in order to determine rotation. This phasing between the two signals is called quadrature. "

"An index or ‘Z’ channel can be provided as one pulse per revolution signal for homing and pulse count verification on the A and/or B channels. This index can be gated to either A or B in their various states. It can also be un-gated and vary in width. "

"Commutation (U, V, W) channels can also be provided on some encoders. These signals are aligned to the commutation windings found on servo motors. They also ensure that the drive or amplifier for those motors apply current to each winding in the correct sequence and at the correct level. "

Comment: How would I go about connecting this? I'm guessing the A and A+ are opposites of the same coils. But, what is an output and what is an input? Is everything an input?

Comment: As EE75 mentions, there are a few different ways that these signals are configured. Without more info, you'll just have to try them. "Open collector" means that the wires are either shorted or disconnected to indicate 0 or 1. The other scheme he mentions is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The pairs may be open collector or 40mA differential drivers.

- Z channel = Index  for homing and pulse count verification on the A and/or B channels
- This index can be gated to either A or B in their various states. It can also be un-gated and vary in width.

  ### - Commutation (U, V, W) channels are in sync with power coils.